# Show all issues unlabeled on Github

Tags: github

Is it currently a way to display only unlabeled issues on GitHub? Having a look at the [advance search docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-label) doesn't really yield any useful information except for the `-label` flag that excludes a series of labels.

The use case is that in my repo I have over 80 labels and just migrated over 100 issues from another repository into another, therefore all new issues are unlabeled, I would like to bulk select those unlabeled and label them as `needs-triage`. The on top-of-my-head solution I can think of is filtering them by date ranges, but that's sub-optimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When searching, use:

```
is:issue is:open no:label
```